# python 32 invalid syntax but works in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am currently facing an issue where it says invalid syntax error, when the game is run on python 3, however, it works without any problems on python 2.

Can you please advise why am getting an invalid syntax error when using python3?

```
class Ammo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, (width, height)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 0
        self.vector = 0
```

I am getting a `SyntaxError` in the line

```
def __init__(self, color, (width, height)):
```

I would like to make the above code work on python 3 without having any other issues and problems.

Comment: Well, yes, that's invalid syntax in Python 3. What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix this in python 3.

Comment: @tobias_k Pygame is available for Python 3.

Comment: I know its available, but how can I make the above code work in python 3.

Comment: [PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Comment: Python 3 does not support tuple-unpacking in argument lists any longer. Have you tried changing your code to `def __init__(self, color, width_height):` and `self.image = pygame.Surface(width_height)`?

Comment: What do I replace it with. any sample code please.

Comment: I already replaced it in my comment. Look carefully.

Comment: Yes, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

[Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) has been removed in Python 3.

You have two options: You could either write your `__init__` method like this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, color, width, height):
...         print(color, width, height)
```

and initialize the object by supplying three arguments or by unpacking the tuple with the width and height values in them that you might have:

```
>>> wh = (1, 0)
>>> Foo('blue', *wh)
blue 1 0
```

Alternatively, if you want `__init__` to take two arguments from the user:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, color, width_and_height):
...         width, height = width_and_height
...         print(color, width, height)
```

where the initialization looks like this:

```
>>> Foo('blue', wh)
blue 1 0
```

I prefer the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple parameters are no longer support in Python3: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

You may unpack your tuple at the beginning of your function:

```
def add_vectors(v1, v2):
    angle_1, l_1 = v1
    angle_2, l_2 = v2
    x=math.sin(angle1)*l_1+math.sin(angle2)*l_2
    y=math.cos(angle1)*l_1+math.cos(angle2)*l_2

    angle=0.5*math.pi-math.atan2(y, x)
    length=math.hypot(x, y)
    return (angle, length)
```